# Differential equation with tangent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you help me with solving such a differential equation:
$$y dx - x dy = 2x^3 \tan (\frac{y}{x})dx$$
I don't have any idea how to start it.
I've thought about substitution $z=\frac{y}{x}$ and checked that it isn't exact differential equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ydx-xdy=2x^3\tan({y\over x})dx\\\implies {xdy-ydx\over x^2}=-2x\tan({y\over x})dx\\\implies {d({y\over x})\over \tan({y\over x})}=-2xdx$$

There you go!

Comment: So now I should integrate both sides and then I get:
$\int {d({y\over x})\over \tan({y\over x})}=-2 \int xdx $
I use substitute $z=\frac{y}{x}$:
$\int {\cos(z) dz\over \sin(z)}=-x^2+c  $ and then
$\ln(\sin(\frac{y}{x}))=-x^2+c$

Comment: @Z.Princc Perfect

Comment: And at the end we get: $y=x\arcsin(c*e^{-x^2})$